# xslt and passing parameters (query strings)

Tags: xml, xslt, filter, query-string

I have a list of users in my xml file and this is what I have in xslt:

```
<a >
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="@First_Name"/>
        <xsl:text>_</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@Last_Name"/>
        <xsl:text>.xml</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@First_Name"/>
    <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@Last_Name"/>
</a>
```

now.... there is another xml file which contains detailed info of each user.
How can I pass  "@id" to and use it as a filter?
or can I?

Comment: Are you trying to combine data from both xml files on an `id` attribute?

Comment: Are you trying to construct a file name dynamically at run time and then read in and process the contents of this file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use data from a second xml document by making use of the [`document()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) function.

For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="value" select="some-value"/>
<xsl:value-of select="document('users.xml')/users/user[@id=$value]"/>
```

It may also be more convenient to load the second document as an `<xsl:variable>` if you will be needing to access it frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the file with user details is called details.xml. 
And it has got the following structure:

```
  <detail id='aaa'>
  </detail>
  <detail id='bbb'>
  </detail>
```

Then you can add these lines to your code :

```
  <xsl:variable name="userId" select="@id" />
  <xsl:value-of select="document('details.xml')/detail[@id=$userId]"/>
```

Comment: do you know a way that I can pass ID to other xml file like :
<a href="users.xml?USERID=xxx"> name family</a>
 and process the passed ID in that file ?(I mean the xsl file which is transforming it like "users.xslt" )

Comment: It doesn't make a sense and is impossible to pass id parameter to other XML.

Comment: @Dennis, please accept the answers if they could really solve your problems .. and do not extend the same question to new requirement .. if you really have a need of the heavily extended requirement then ask a new question.